# Hive Could not obtain block

Tags: hadoop, block, hive

I am getting the problem

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Could not obtain block: blk_364919282277866885_1342 file=/user/hive/warehouse/invites/ds=2008-08-08/kv3.txt

I checked the file is actually there.

```
hive>dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/invites/ds=2008-08-08/kv3.txt
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   2 root supergroup        216 2012-11-16 16:28 /user/hive/warehouse/invites/ds=2008-08-08/kv3.txt
```

What I should do?

Please help.

Comment: There might be certain tweaks you might have to do on your cluster if you are using a basic linux machine with hadoop installed on it. http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/03/configuration-parameters-what-can-you-just-ignore/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem on my cluster, but it disappeared once I restarted the task on a cluster with more nodes available.  The underlying cause appears to be an out-of-memory error, as [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=201849#201849) indicates.  My original cluster on AWS was running 3 c1.xlarge instances (7 GB memory each), while the new one had 10 c3.4xlarge instances (30 GB memory each).

Answer (score 0):

Try `hadoop fsck /user/hive/warehouse/invites/ds=2008-08-08/kv3.txt` ?